# Attempted import error: 'ToogleButton' is not exported from '@material-ui/lab'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When trying to instantiate ToogleButton in the code, its throwing the error message: Attempted import error: 'ToogleButton' is not exported from '@material-ui/lab'.

`import { ToogleButton } from '@material-ui/lab';`

Versions:

```
- @material-ui/core@4.9.8
- @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-aplha.47
- react@16.13.1
- react-dom@16.13.1
```

Comment: Try without the curly brackets `import ToggleButton from '@material-ui/lab/ToggleButton'`

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Install this version of lab : "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.46",

Comment: Hello, I pulled the component like this and that worked just fine: import ToogleButton from '@material-ui/lab/ToggleButton';

Comment: Hmm, I tried in my project import { ToogleButton } from '@material-ui/lab' and it work too it's weird